# PhpStorm | Web server folder and project root aren't the same

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I'm trying to make a project with a public folder inside. That folder is where the web server is pointing at, but I can't make PhpStorm to understand that and open in the built-in browser the correct URL.

I mean:

```
Project root
|-- app
|-- config
|-- core
`-- public (Web server root folder)
    `-- index.php
```

Comment: Sure: 1) Create a deployment entry and mark as Default for this project 2) on Mappings tab create additional entry: local = path to `public`; web path = `/`. When you now will be using"Open in Browser" or alike feature, the URL will be build with `public` folder mapping in mind.

Comment: P.S. For internal usage (e.g. path resolving etc) better also mark `public` as a Resource Root (via right click menu in Project View panel .. or manually via "Settings | Directories")

Comment: @LazyOne thanks! Now work without problem! I also remove the default mapping entry to avoid try to open backend files, doesn't have too much sense but it's for perfection.
The mapping is a bit confusing for me I have to recognize it.

Comment: I suggest you post it as an answer and later accept it. But do it with pics (I will edit it to make them pics and not links if needed). This will help others who will face similar issue.